# How to get out of a hiring process during a phone interview?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process

Few days ago i was contacted by a recruiter from a reputable company inviting me to the hiring process for a business development role in their company, and as i had no clear idea of what that is i asked to learn more and shared my contacts. Later they scheduled a phone interview and shared the job description and responsibilities which to me looked like it has a lot of sales in it.

I have no experience in sales and my whole career consists of technical jobs whether it's IT, development, or other jobs. I have no clue why they contacted me but nothing i read in the description they sent make it sound like something i can/want to do but at the same time i accepted the phone interview. My question here is how do i get out of it politely without sounding like in incompetent person or someone who is just wasting their recruiter's time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> My question here is how do i get out of it politely without sounding
>   like in incompetent person or someone who is just wasting their
>   recruiter's time?

Something like "Thank you for the opportunity. But after thinking it over I have decided that this isn't a role I want."

Comment: Agreed. Would additionally note that it would be wasting the recruiter's time more to take part in a phone interview knowing that there is no interest in progressing further.